Read Only User: "show run" not working
I want to create a read-only user for a script. I want the user to execute show running-config and make a backup.
The switch is a Cisco 9200L, running SW Version 17.03.05.
I've created a user, but show run isn't working.
These are the commands I used for this purpose:
SWone(config)#privilege exec level 3 show running-config privilege

And then the USER
username ronly privilege 3 secret 0 password

However, when I log in with "ronly," this happens:
SWone#show running-config
SWone#

It  doesn't retrieve any configuration.
Any idea?
Thank you so much.

#1) Per Cisco documentation: "This is because the show running-config  command displays all of the commands that the user is able to modify at their current privilege level."
#2) Per Cisco documentation: "From 16.X version, depending on the platform it is also required to add permissions to the files using the command (config)#file privilege <level>."
Configure Full Running Config for Users with Low Privilege Levels -- aforementioned Cisco Documentation
In other words: 1) The user's privilege level needs permission access files. 2) The logged in user will only see commands in the running-config that their privilege level allows. Even if they're privileged to use "show running-config" -and- access files.
Cisco says: "As a solution to this dilemma, there is another version of the traditional show run command that bypasses this limitation of the command."
show running-config view full
Which the users level has to be privileged to access, too. (e.g. "privilege exec level 3 show running-config view full")

Thanks a lot, man!

Just had to solve this problem myself - programming a network for a client.
